# Получение данных от invoice платежа PyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Имеется вот такой кусочек кода, который позволяет отправить счет на оплату товара в телеграм боте.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['buy'])
def command_pay(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     "sometext"
                     "sometext"
                     "\n\nThis is your demo invoice:", parse_mode='Markdown')
    bot.send_invoice(message.chat.id, title='Working Time Machine',
                     description='sometext',
                     provider_token=provider_token,
                     currency='rub',
                     photo_url='someurl',
                     photo_height=512,  # !=0/None or picture won't be shown
                     photo_width=512,
                     photo_size=512,
                     need_shipping_address=True,
                     need_name=True,
                     need_phone_number=True,
                     is_flexible=False,  # True If you need to set up Shipping Fee
                     prices=prices,
                     start_parameter='time-machine-example',
                     invoice_payload='HAPPY FRIDAYS COUPON')
```

Каким образом можно получить данные, которые покупатель вписал в поля доставка, телефон, имя? Я могу получить эти данные на этапе pre_checkout_query, но при этом платеж еще не будет подтвержден.

Answer (score 0):

PS: перечитав документацию, все таки нашел ответ на свой вопрос. Для получения нам требуется в хэндлере, обрабатывающем успешную оплату вывести такие данные:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['successful_payment'])
def got_payment(message):
     print(message.successful_payment.order_info)
```

В итоге мы получаем все данные, которые указал пользователь при оплате.